# Sign of Fractional Exponents

Tags: exponentiation, radicals

When calculating a number to a fractional exponent or fractional nth root, in what cases is there both a positive and negative solution as opposed to just a positive or just a negative solution?

Comment: Short answer: when the denominator is even. Slightly longer answer: $x^\frac{1}{2a}$ is often defined to mean the positive root. If you want the negative root (or both) you should explicitly use the negative (or plus/minus) sign.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the comment of user164587:

A $n$-th root of $a$ is *by definition* a solution of
$$x^n=a.$$
If the exponent is odd, the function
$$x\longmapsto x^n$$
is increasing and the equation has only one solution (the function $y=x^n$ and the horizontal line $y=a$ intersect at a single point).

But if $n$ is even...